# HDD writes are faster on VM (Vagrant box) and slower on bare metal (host)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, performance

HDD writes are slow on ubuntu running on bare metal. I started a Vagrant box on the same host (running same version of Ubuntu) and writes are very fast compared to bare metal.

Following are the output of various HDD performance related commands from both Host and VM. Any idea what should I fine tune to improve write speed on bare metal?

Bare Metal

> `$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output  bs=384k count=1k oflag=dsync
>   1024+0 records in
>   1024+0 records out
>   402653184 bytes (403 MB) copied, 37.4866 s, 10.7 MB/s`

VM (Vagrant Box)

> `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output  bs=384k count=1k oflag=dsync
>   1024+0 records in
>   1024+0 records out
>   402653184 bytes (403 MB) copied, 0.923299 s, 436 MB/s`

On host,

> `$ lsblk -l
>   NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
>   sda    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
>   sda1   8:1    0 802.9G  0 part
>   md0    9:0    0 802.8G  0 raid1 /
>   sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
>   sda5   8:5    0  35.5G  0 part
>   md1    9:1    0  35.4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
>   sda6   8:6    0  93.1G  0 part
>   md2    9:2    0  93.1G  0 raid1 /home
>   sdb    8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
>   sdb1   8:17   0 802.9G  0 part
>   md0    9:0    0 802.8G  0 raid1 /
>   sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
>   sdb5   8:21   0  35.5G  0 part
>   md1    9:1    0  35.4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
>   sdb6   8:22   0  93.1G  0 part
>   md2    9:2    0  93.1G  0 raid1 /home
>   $ mount | grep md0
>   /dev/md0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)`

On VM

> `$ lsblk -l
>   NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>   sda    8:0    0  40G  0 disk
>   sda1   8:1    0  40G  0 part /
>   $ mount | grep sda1
>   /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)`

HDD Info from Host

> `$ hdparm -I /dev/sda
>   /dev/sda:
>   ATA device, with non-removable media
>           Model Number:       ST1000NM0033-9ZM173
>           Serial Number:      Z1W3BGQQ
>           Firmware Revision:  SN04
>           Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
>   Standards:
>           Supported: 9 8 7 6 5
>           Likely used: 9
>   Configuration:
>           Logical         max     current
>           cylinders       16383   16383
>           heads           16      16
>           sectors/track   63      63
>           --
>           CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
>           LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
>           LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
>           Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
>           Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
>           Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
>           device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
>           device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
>           cache/buffer size  = unknown
>           Form Factor: 3.5 inch
>           Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing memory caching or virtualization layer recognizing zeros in data stream, and thus creating a sparse record in the drive image.

>400MB/s, like reported by the VM is totally unrealistic on 7200rpm drives. 120-150MB/s is realistic, but high, continuous write speed, >400MB/s is not.

To test if it's memory caching, select a *large* write, like two times the total memory of the box. This removes the write cache impact from the equation, and will tell you if the virtualization layer does some trickery with all nulls.

You can also try to read a non-zero data-file, like an ISO, and see what write performance you get then. If it's equally fast, it also means that data is not actually written to disk, but merely cached *somewhere*.

On a system with a recently trimmed ssd, I reach 42MB/s. This is probably slower than the disk can do in sequential write, as dsync means synchronous I/O operation. If I change the block size to 1M and the count to 400, I reach approx. 80MB/s on SSD's, indicating that the sync operation plays a large role in the low speed.